# 'to.include' is not working where 'to.eventually.equal' is working

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I was trying to check whether a string is present in another string.I am using the below code
`expect(actualTimeZone).to.include(employee.timeZone);`

But it is giving the below error

`AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given`

But when I tried with the below code, it is not throwing the above error
`expect(actualTimeZone).to.eventually.equal(employee.timeZone);`

I am working on protractor framework with cucumber and javascript. Could someone help to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the below code and it is working

`expect(actualTimeZone).to.eventually.include(employee.timeZone);`

Comment: Can you accept your answer . dont accept when you need more clarity on this question.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or
> a weakset, but object given

happens when you are returning a set of web elements (which is an object not an array) and you try to treat them like an regular array.

So, first you have to extract the array from the object, then map each element getting the desire attribute, and finally filtering to prevent empty or null values.

Below an example step by step, using cucumber and JavaScript in Cypress.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getTableData', () => {
// This is the table in the front-end, we read it completely and save it in an alias called table
cy.get('[data-test="table-body"]').find('tr').as('table')

// Now we apply the logic explained before
cy.get('@table').then(row => {
    let arr = Object.keys(row)
    return arr.map(element => { return row[element].textContent })
        .filter(element => element)
})
```

})

Now, we can use the method above and use it to execute any expect like .includes (which was your issue)

```
And('Verify the value is in the table', () => {
  cy.getTableData().then(arr => {
    expect(arr).includes(assetName)
  })
})
```

Also, with the same method we can loop through the entire array and do anything with each element:

```
And('Verify the value is in the tablex', () => {
  cy.getTableData().each(element => {
    cy.log(element)
  })
})
```